# How to capture the rails migration errors?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

While running the rake db:migrate, i will get errors such as table does not exists etc. How to capture these errors?

Comment: You are not supposed to write migrations that will throw errors. “Table does not exist” e.g. might be easily checked with `if table_exists` guard directly in a mutation. General rule is: migrations are not to throw exceptions. BTW, this is not how questions on SO are supposedly asked, please read [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't think this question is closable for the nominated reason ("too broad").  I'll vote to leave open.  However, as asked, it's not a good question--some code, examples of the erroneous output, etc., would sure improve it.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like your table contain foreign key run before primary table.
you can easily determine with your log and change sequence of migration to run your dependent table first. so, you can easily get rid of this.

Ex. suppose you have two tables `'user'` and `'role'`. user has many roles.
then `'role'` table must contain user's id as foreign key.

> In this case user table must be created before role table.